# papertrail set up

Tags: android, papertrail-app

I can't believe I am having to ask this but I have no idea where to turn. I have Googled loads but not come up with anything.

I am looking to use papertrail instead of bugsnag for logging on my android application.

I have been given some code (seen below) to add to a configuration file. I have no idea where to put this file, the manifest? a new file? in the gradle bits?

Any help appreciated.

```
<configuration> 
  <appender name="syslog-tls" class="com.papertrailapp.logback.Syslog4jAppender"> 
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
      <pattern>%d{MMM dd HH:mm:ss} Android YOUR_APP: %-5level %logger{35} %m%n</pattern>
    </layout>

    <syslogConfig class="org.productivity.java.syslog4j.impl.net.tcp.ssl.SSLTCPNetSyslogConfig"> 
      <host>logsN.papertrailapp.com</host> 
      <port>XXXXX</port> 
      <sendLocalName>false</sendLocalName>
      <sendLocalTimestamp>false</sendLocalTimestamp> 
      <maxMessageLength>128000</maxMessageLength> 
    </syslogConfig> 
  </appender>

  <appender name="async" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender"> 
    <appender-ref ref="syslog-tls" /> 
  </appender>

  <root level="INFO"> 
    <appender-ref ref="async" /> 
  </root> 
</configuration>
```

Comment: You sir might be right, but if you look at this link I would doubt that. https://help.papertrailapp.com/kb/configuration/configuring-centralized-logging-from-android-apps/

Comment: But I am looking to use papertrail. Not logback.

Comment: it reads `ch.qos.logback` (the pattern layout & the appender) ...doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue (and I'd say Papertrail's Android setup instructions are seriously poor)

Turns out

1. You first need to setup either `logback-sys4j` or `logback-android`

(I chose `logback-android` - instructions here: http://tony19.github.io/logback-android/).

2. This shows that you need to add `logback.xml` under `/app/src/main/assets/logback.xml`
3. Then update **host** and **port** in your `logback.xml` (You can find these on Papertrail dashboard *Settings > Log Destinations*)

Then you will start getting logs on the Papertrail dashboard

**Warning**: When you choose *Selected application only* in logcat, your logs won't show because Papertrail logs don't contain the application name (unless you configure otherwise) by default

Comment: if I follow the above instructions. Papertrail logs are working fine in Debug build. If i build the release version, I am not able to view the logs in Papertrail dashboard. What might be the issue ?

Comment: Upvoting because this was more clear than PaperTrail's instructions, but it still didn't get the logs to send. I guess this means PaperTrail won't be a good solution for us. It doesn't seem to be keeping up with Android, given that the gradle dependencies still use "compile" instead of "implementation".

Answer (score 1):

that configuration file belongs to `assets/logback.xml` ...

and PaperTrail suggests to use http://tony19.github.io/logback-android/

eg. https://github.com/tony19/logback-android/wiki#configuration-via-xml

Comment: I need to be able to see the logs online this doesn't look like it provides that

Comment: there might be a "slight difference" in between a (local) logging library and an online service (while it is religious to believe, that the one would exclude the other)... why do you think they would suggest it themselves, if it would not be leading towards those logs being fed into the service?